# jquery when(): different behaviour for one vs multiple thenables

Tags: javascript, jquery

[`jQuery.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) can be used to execute callbacks when a thenable object is done.

I find it useful, since it can group multiple thenable objects:

```
promise1.then((v1)=>{
  promise2.then((v2)=>{
    promise3.then((v3)=>{
      // arrow pattern ... 
    })         
  })
})

// converts to
$.when(promise1, promise2, promise3)
.done((v1, v2, v3)=>{
  // yay, nice and flat
});
```

But now I found that the function behaves differently when I provide one vs multiple thenables. In the case of multiple thenables, `when()` seems to record additional information, the actual return is accessible over `v1[0]`.

I've set up a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/989940/

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><div id="result1"></div></li>
<br>
<li><div id="result2"></div></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$.when(
    $.get("https://httpbin.org/get")
).done((v1)=>[
  $("#result1").html(v1["url"])
])

$.when(
    $.get("https://httpbin.org/get"),
    $.get("https://httpbin.org/get")
).done((v1, v2)=>[
  $("#result2").html(v1[0]["url"])
])
```

Comment: According to the docs: In the case where multiple Deferred objects are passed to jQuery.when(), the method returns the Promise from a new "master" Deferred object that tracks the aggregate state of all the Deferreds it has been passed. (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a quirk in that  `$.ajax.then()` has multiple arguments and `$.when` will return all those arguments only when multiple promises are passed in

One workaround is add `then()` for each request

```js
$.when(
    $.get("https://httpbin.org/get").then(d=>d),
    $.get("https://httpbin.org/get").then(d=>d)
).then((v1, v2)=>{
  console.log(v1["url"])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or use `Promise.all()` which ignores the secondary arguments of `$.ajax.then()`

```js
Promise.all([$.get("https://httpbin.org/get"), $.get("https://httpbin.org/get")])
  .then(res => console.log(res[0].url))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find any documentation that tells me why exactly the result is converted to a 3-ary array in the multiple-case but not the single-case.

Since your post is suspiciously devoid of an actual question, I assume you simply want to force both calls to behave in the same manner? You could achieve this by passing a null-promise as a virtual second parameter in the single-call case:

```
$.when(
    $.get("https://httpbin.org/get"),
    null
).done((v1)=>[
  $("#result0").html(JSON.stringify(v1))
])
```

Which will make JQuery use the same array-notation for the result as in the multi-case

```
$.when(
    $.get("https://httpbin.org/get"),
    $.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
).done((v1,v2)=>{
  $("#result1").html(JSON.stringify(v1))
  $("#result2").html(JSON.stringify(v2))
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/990023/